# How can I get the value of the existing variable in a IF clause?

Tags: objective-c, c

I am working on Objective C and I want to do something like this:

```
if (a && !b) {
  // a do something...
} else if (!a && b) {
  // b do something...
}
```

I wondered if there is something simpler, like:

```
if (a XOR b) {
  // the existing variable do something...
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are `a` and `b` guaranteed to be boolean values? Or can they be integer values like `3` and `5`?

Comment: @user3386109 a and b should be just some variable containing string, number or any object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective C is a superset of C, use the `^` operator. Or you can think logically (since xor is only true if either is true and the other is false) and use:

```
// This won't work for all types, be careful
if (a != b){
    if (a){
        // a do something
    }   
    if (b){
        // b do something
    }
}
```

Note this solution, expanded from the xor, is more lengthy than the one you provided.

Comment: *quick tip* Keep in mind, you cannot rely on default values for booleans here. For some reason, although the default value for both is false, this may produce a true output unless the booleans are explicitly set to `false`.

Comment: but how do I get the existing value in this clause?

Comment: What do you mean by existing value?

Comment: The if clause above can only tell me if either of a or b exists, and return TRUE or FALSE. Is there any way to know which variable exists, and then pass that variable (a or b) down to do some function?

Comment: I see, I must have misinterpreted your question. Other than a nested if or the first bit of code you provided, I don't think there is a better solution.

Comment: No worries. But that is a pain to write down all the conditions. It would be easy if I only have a and b two variables, but imagine having 5 variables. I just thought there would be a clever way to do it. Thanks anyway

Comment: Are you making the assumption that only one of the variables is true?

Comment: No, it could be a && b && !c, and all exists, and either one exists... just all the possible conditions

Comment: You can store all of the values in an NSMuteableArray, iterate through the array with an if conditional and if the value exists then call the function.

Answer (score 1):

well I'm not sure if I misunderstood, but I guess a possibly solution would be to use the ? operator.

```
void *aux;
if( aux = a ? (b ? NULL : a) : (b ?  b : NULL) )
    //working with aux here
```

Never the less, if the idea is to keep it simple, this is quite unreadable. Also, this would expand to something like:

```
void *aux;
if(a){
    if(b)
         aux = NULL;
    else
         aux = a;
}else{
    if(b)
         aux = b;
    else
         aux = NULL;
}
```

My suggestion is that you leave the code as is. It's more readable and in terms of performance, I don't believe you'll notice much difference between the approaches

edit for clarity:
BTW, Inside the if block, the aux var will contain the value that exists. And if aux is NULL  the if block won't be entered. Also, aux doesn't have to be void * or a pointer, it only has to be compatible with a and b datatypes.

Comment: Wouldn't this get out of hand if the OP had, say, 6 variables instead of 2?

Comment: @Andriko13 yep, totally. I guess the number of ? operators will be the sum from i=0 up to the number of variables -1 of 2^i

in latex: $\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} 2^i$

Answer (score 0):

```
if( !a != !b ) // same as a xor b
```

Comment: Why not just remove the `!` before a and b for simplicity?